# How to retain ajax variable when posting to another php page?

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post

Ok, so I know with the POST method it should be fairly easy to post an ajax variable to another php page, but for some reason it's not working. It get the value i want but the POST method doesn't work in the page I post it too.

I'm trying to send the value of the variable to a php page for it to use on a query. I've tried storing it in a session variable on the same page to use on the next one, I've tried using the POST method, GET method, but it only shows me the value on the alert and then erases it. Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are my pages:

clubexistentes.php

```html
<?php 
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db4h/login/includes/db_connect.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/db4h/login/includes/functions.php");
include_once 'connecexist.php';
include_once 'sociocount.php';
 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."db4h/login/includes/session.class.php");
$session = new session();
// Set to true if using https
$session->start_session('_s', false);

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}

if($_SESSION["level"] !=="admin") {
 //redirect
 header("location: ../login/index.php");
} else {
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."db4h/login/includes/agt-select.php");
}

?>

<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/db4h/login/main/main.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Codigo </th>
    <th>Nombre </th>
    <th>Lider </th>
    <th>Socios </th>
   </tr>
    <?php if(isset($nombreClub)){ for($y = 0; $y <count($nombreClub); $y++) {
        echo "<tr>" . 
        "<td>" .  "<a href='http://localhost/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/clubdetail.php' class='click_row' id=' " . $id[$y] . " '>" .  $id[$y] . "</a>" . "</td> " . 
        "<td>" . $nombreClub[$y] . "</td>" . 
        "<td>" . $liderVoluntario[$y] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $memberSearch[$y][0] . "</td>" .
        "</tr>" . "";
       }}
    ?>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</fieldset>
<script>

$('.click_row').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    $link = $(this);
    // Here where you will do you ajax call or what ever else 

  $.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/clubdetail.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: { 'myvar' : this.id },
   success: function(data) {
    var myvar = data;
    alert(data);
    window.location.href = $link.attr('href');
   } 
  });
});

</script>
<p><input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://localhost/db4h/login/clubes/clubes.php'" value='Regresar'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the page i'm trying to pass it to
detailconnection.php

```html
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$nombreClub = $liderVoluntario = $id = $pass = "";

  if (isset($_POST['myvar'])) {
  $pass = $_POST['myvar'];
    } 
try {
 
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=4h', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $sql = "SELECT id, nombreClub, liderVoluntario FROM club4h WHERE id LIKE ' " . $pass . " '; ";
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
      $nombreClub = $row["nombreClub"];
      $liderVoluntario = $row["liderVoluntario"];
      $id = $row["id"];
     } 
   

   $res = null;
   $conn = null;
 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

and the page i'm trying to display the query in
clubdetail.php

```html
<?php 
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db4h/login/includes/db_connect.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/db4h/login/includes/functions.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/connecexist.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/sociocount.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/detailconnection.php");

 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."db4h/login/includes/session.class.php");
$session = new session();
// Set to true if using https
$session->start_session('_s', false);

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}

if($_SESSION["level"] !=="admin") {
 //redirect
 header("location: ../login/index.php");
} else {
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."db4h/login/includes/agt-select.php");
}

echo $_POST["myvar"];

?>

<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/db4h/login/main/main.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<label></label>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Club: <?php echo $nombreClub; ?> </th>
    <th>Lider: <?php echo $liderVoluntario ?></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</fieldset>
<p><input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://localhost/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/clubesexistentes.php'" value='Regresar'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm missing something miniscule, I'm no expert at java but what's odd to me is to see the value in the alert but not be able to retrieve it.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Narrow down your code to the relevant parts.

Comment: If you see the "id" in the alert, that means that it is working correctly, there's no problem with your code. You've sent it through `data: { 'myvar' : this.id },`, in PHP you echoed `echo $_POST["myvar"];` it back, then displayed it again to the user `alert(data);`.

Comment: well, when I echo it in the next page (from clubesexistentes.php to detailconnection.php) it is null, that's why. 

p.s.: sorry bout posting all the code guys.

Comment: this is what shows when i click on the href on the next page:

Notice: Undefined index: myvar in C:\wamp\www\db4h\login\clubes\exsistentes\clubdetail.php on line 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make an AJAX post to `clubdetail.php`, it will have the POST variables, but when you do `window.location.href = $link.attr('href');`, that is a GET request to `clubdetail.php`. If all you want to do is navigate to `clubdetail.php`, then drop the AJAX (`$('.click_row').click()`) and just put the `id` in your for loop:

```
<?php 
if(isset($nombreClub)){
    for($y = 0; $y <count($nombreClub); $y++) {
        echo "<tr>" . 
        "<td>" .  "<a href='http://localhost/db4h/login/clubes/exsistentes/clubdetail.php?id=" . $id[$y] . "' class='click_row' id=' " . $id[$y] . " '>" .  $id[$y] . "</a>" . "</td> " . 
        "<td>" . $nombreClub[$y] . "</td>" . 
        "<td>" . $liderVoluntario[$y] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $memberSearch[$y][0] . "</td>" .
        "</tr>" . "";
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your `clubdetail.php` you access it by:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Also, it seems that you're trying to access the `id` property the wrong way. You've already created a jQuery variable with `$link = $(this);`, so instead of

```
data: { 'myvar' : this.id },
```

try

```
data: { 'myvar' : $link.attr('id') },
```

Comment: Tried it and got Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the answer. You have made `$link = $(this);`, so `$link` is a jQuery object. On that object you can use the `attr()` function.

Comment: it still gives me and undefined index on the clubdetail.php page.

weird thing is whereever i use "echo $_POST["myvar"];" the result appears on the alert popup but not on the php page.

Comment: It won't appear on which php page? If `alert(data);` shows the right id, then certainly `clubdetail.php` is receiving it. If you want to make it appear on `clubexistentes.php `, you have to replace the alert with code to inject it somewhere in the DOM, like `$('#myTargetTag').text(data);`. But it will be available only on client-side.

Comment: it doesn't appear on `clubdetail.php`, i've echoed the variable in both `clubdetail.php` and `detailconnection.php` and it still shows and undefined index when i arrive at the page, but the value is displayed in the  `alert(data)`.

Comment: how do i go about the DOM injection? I'm thinking about trying to inject it in`clubdetail.php` to see if it works. Sorry, I'm new to ajax.

Comment: I have updated my answer. About DOM injection, I suggest you read more about jQuery, and if you have any questions, open a new answer so this one doesn't go too off-topic.

Comment: Thank you sir. You have saved me from frustration. So simple, it's hilarious.